# laravel boot methods not working in the model

Tags: php, laravel

hi im using laravel 8 and im trying to do some code after create or update
like if model has create set created_by = Auth::user()->id ect
and this is my model code

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Helper;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
class Account extends Model
{
    use Notifiable,SoftDeletes,LogsActivity;
    protected static $logAttributes = 
    [
        'number',
        'name',
        'foreign_name',
        'main_account_id',
        'user_id',
        'account_state_id',
        'note',
        'balance_limit',
        'approved_state_id'
    ];
    protected static $logName = 'accounts';
    protected static $logAttributesToIgnore = [ 'updated_at'];
    protected $table = 'accounts';
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'number',
        'name',
        'foreign_name',
        'main_account_id',
        'user_id',
        'account_state_id',
        'note',
        'approved_state_id',
        'balance_limit',
        'created_by','deleted_by'
    ];
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function($model){
            $model->created_by = Auth::user()->id; // this code work
        });
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            dd('asdf'); // this not working
        });

        self::deleting(function($model){
            dd($model); // this not working 
        });
        self::restoring(function($model){
            dd($model); // this not working 
        });
    }
}
```

now the code in

```
static::updating(function ($model) {
    dd('asdf'); // this not working
});
```

is not working when i update any account also in delete and restore
the dd('asdf'); not working

any help here thanks ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to override the `booted` method instead of `boot`. It is an update from laravel 7.

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::created(function ($user) {
        //
    });
}
```

Check the official documentation on [Using Closures](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures)